# Decimal function in SQL Server 2005 not working as intended

Tags: sql, sql-server, function, sql-server-2005, decimal

```
select 
screenname,
count(*) as Total_SignIns
,count(distinct(startdate)) as Uniq_Days_Signin
, ROUND(CONVERT(DECIMAL(4,2), count(*))/CONVERT(DECIMAL(4,2), count(distinct(startdate))), 2) AS AverageDaySingIn
from (
    select distinct(id), x.screenname, startdate, cast(startdate+' '+starttime as datetime) as startdatetime, x.boxadollar
    from sitelive.dbo.exsignin x (nolock)
    inner join (
            select distinct(SenderScreennameSimple), ReceiverScreennameSimple, convert(char(8),dateentered,1) as Poke_date
                ,(select top 1 Dateentered from Temp.dbo.poketemp 
                    where n.ReceiverScreennameSimple = ReceiverScreennameSimple and n.SenderScreennameSimple = SenderScreennameSimple and convert(char(8),n.dateentered,1) = convert(char(8),dateentered,1) 
                    Order by DateEntered) as Poke
                ,(select top 1 Dateentered from Temp.dbo.poketemp 
                    where n.ReceiverScreennameSimple = ReceiverScreennameSimple and n.SenderScreennameSimple = SenderScreennameSimple and convert(char(8),n.dateentered,1) = convert(char(8),dateentered,1) 
                    Order by DateEntered desc) as Poke_Lst
            ,count(*) as Poke_Count
            from Temp.dbo.poketemp n
            Group by SenderScreennameSimple, ReceiverScreennameSimple, convert(char(8),dateentered,1)
            having count(*) = 1
            ) t1 on t1.SenderScreennameSimple = x.screenname
    where datediff(minute,Poke,cast(startdate+' '+starttime as datetime) ) Between 0 and 60 and LiveOrRecorded = 'L'
) t2
Group by  
screenname
```

Above is the sample query I am using the result set contains:

```
AverageDaySignIn
1.0000000
1.0000000
1.0000000
1.0000000
1.0000000
2.4500000
2.0000000
1.6700000
1.0000000
1.3300000... and so on
```

I have even tried:

```
, ROUND(CONVERT(DECIMAL(3,2), count(*))/CONVERT(DECIMAL(3,2), count(distinct(startdate))), 2) AS AverageDaySingIn
```

I get this error:

```
Arithmetic overflow error converting int to data type numeric.
```

What am I doing wrong? Sorry for the noob'ness, any help would be greatly appreciated.  Thank you in advance.

Comment: Try increasing the decimal digits from 4 to 18

Comment: Did so, it increased the digits:
1.00000000000000000000

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like the *numbers* are rounding to 2 digits as you expect, but the *display* is not -  you can use [`STR`](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms189527.aspx) to control the display:

```
SELECT
screenname,
COUNT(*) as Total_SignIns
,COUNT(DISTINCT startdate ) as Uniq_Days_Signin
, STR(
    ROUND(COUNT(*)/COUNT(DISTINCT startdate ), 2) 
    , 10, 2) AS AverageDaySingIn
FROM(
...
```

Comment: This worked, thank you D Stanley! Are there any online articles that explain this STR function? The desired output that I am getting is now:
AverageDaySignIn
      1.00
      1.00
      2.00
      1.00
      1.50
      2.00
      1.00
      1.50
      1.60
      1.67
      3.33
      2.00
      2.00
      1.00
      5.00
      1.00
      1.50
      1.00
      1.00
      1.14
      1.00
      3.00
      2.00
      2.00
      1.67
      4.00
      2.00
      1.00
      2.00
      2.00
      4.00
      4.75
      1.33

Comment: @user2961803 Added a link to the documentation.

Answer (score 0):

`DECIMAL(4,2)` allows you to have 2 decimal places and only 2 digits to the left of the decimal point. From the definition of `decimal` on [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187746%28v=sql.90%29.aspx):

> **decimal[ (p[ , s] )]**
>   p = precision - The maximum total number of decimal digits that can be stored, both to the left and to the right of the decimal point. The precision must be a value from 1 through the maximum precision of 38. The default precision is 18.

You should increase your precision to allow for greater numbers, e.g. to `DECIMAL(18,2)`.